# nested divs within a div wont overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a few nested divs, an outer, then a page wrapper and then two divs inside the page wraper. the two divs in there are generated and added to the page wrapper. if the 2 divs have the same top and left values the divs dont over lap but wrap below the previous div.
 attached is the code i have so far. i need the 2 divs in the page wrapper to not wrap like it is.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
 .outer-container
            {
                overflow:auto;
                height:900px;
                width: 900px;
                border:1px solid black;
                background-color:yellow;
                padding:5px;

            }
#page-wrapper { width: 800px; height:700px; border:2px solid #ccc; padding: 0px; background-color:white; position:relative }

</style>

<div class="outer-container">
    <div id="page-wrapper" >
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    classvalue = "draggable ui-widget-content divimage";
    idvalue= "div1";
    thisdiv = '<div style="height:100;width:100;background-color:blue;top:1;left:1;z-index:0;margin:0px" id="'+idvalue+'" class="'+classvalue+'"></div>';
    $('#page-wrapper').append(thisdiv);
    idvalue= "div2"
thisdiv2 = '<div style="height:100;width:100;background-color:teal;top:2;left:2;z-index:1" id="'+idvalue+'" class="'+classvalue+'"></div>';
    $('#page-wrapper').append(thisdiv2);
</script>
```

Comment: coordonates need a unit for their values, unless value is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it right you want the 2 generated divs to overlap? Just add `position:absolute;` to those divs.

And don't forget to put a unit (px) to your top/left/width/...